# Excel VBA to pull a value after a HTML span

Tags: html, excel, vba

New to VBA.  Trying to pull this Value "001500" from HTML using VBA in excel.

```
> <br> 
> 
> <span class="resultItem">TRACT CODE: </span> 
> 
> 001500 
> 
> <br>
```

I have been using this - but it only pulls the info in the span

```
Dim sdiv As String 
sdiv = Trim(doc.getElementsByClassName("resultItem")(85).innerText)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried childnode, and a ton of other items, but no luck.

Comment: You should probably check to see if `getElementsByClassName` returned a value or not first, before trying to access data associated with it. How do you know it will always be the 85th one?

Comment: `sdiv = Trim(doc.getElementsByClassName("resultItem")(85).NextSibling.NodeValue)`